# Clone a WPF element with a Setter

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization

In my WPF application, I have a TabControl with TabItems :

```
<TabItem.Header>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Name ="TabHeader"/>
        <Image Margin="7,0,0,0">
            <Image.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="Pictures/CroixRouge.png"/> // No error without this line         
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
    </StackPanel>
</TabItem.Header>
```

And I clone this TabItem to add one in the TabControl with the following function :

```
TabItem ti = (TabItem)_tabControlList.Items.GetItemAt(_tabControlList.Items.Count - 1);
TabItem tiCloned= TrycloneElement<TabItem>(ti);

private static T TrycloneElement<T>(T orig)
{
    try
    {
        string s = System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(orig); // ERROR : Impossible to serialize a non-public type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrameDecode'

        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(s);

        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlTextReader.Create(stringReader, new XmlReaderSettings());
        XmlReaderSettings sx = new XmlReaderSettings();

        object x = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
        return (T)x;
    }
    catch
    {
        return (T)((object)null);
    }

}
```

Why this error appear ? When I place the image with :

```
<TabItem.Header>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Name ="TabHeader"/>
        <Image Margin="7,0,0,0" Source="Pictures/CroixRouge.png"/>
    </StackPanel>
</TabItem.Header>
```

I have no problem. But I have to use the `<Setter...>` to change the image source on mouse hover.

Comment: not sure why you have to clone something when what you want is just this ***change the image source on mouse hover***?

Comment: I need to clone one tabItem with all his properties to add some others tabitems.